# What is the difference between a Mac mini and a Mac mini server (late-2012)?

Tags: mac-mini, server.app

I've been over the tech specs for both the high-end mac mini with the fusion drive and the mac mini server (http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/mac_mini) and I cannot find more than a single difference; the server has two HDDs (oh, and it ships with os x server installed).

Am I missing something or are you paying $200 more for a second HDD? Or $150 more for a 1TB fusion drive vs 256GB SSD and 1 TB HDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide what you want in terms of storage, performance and OS since there is no option to have 2x1TB drives in the $799 model and there's no option to have a 1TB Fusion Drive in the $999 model.

Essentially, you're paying $200 more to get OS X Server and for the ability to have a second hard drive (doing it yourself is an option if you can follow guides on iFixit and have the tools and accessories required).

---

Choose the $799 model with:

1. A 1TB Fusion Drive - $250
2. OS X Server - $19.99

Total: $1068.99 (but you'll have a faster drive but half the storage space of the default $999 model).

---

Choose the $799 model with the default 1TB drive:

1. add another 1TB 2.5" 5400 rpm drive - about $80+ (approximate cost from newegg)
2. OS X Server - $19.99
3. The [Mac mini Dual Hard Drive kit from iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Apple-Parts/Mac-Mini-Dual-Hard-Drive-Kit/IF171-005) - $49.95

Total: $948.94
Hassle of doing it yourself: Priceless